# what is the issue with this SOQL query

Tags: soql

```
 for(lead L:trigger.new)
    {
        if(L.postalcode !=null)
        {
            List<Territory__c> terrList[select id from Territory__c where posatalcode__c: L.posatalcode];
            if(terrList.size()>0)
            {
                L.Territory__c=terrList[0].id;
            }

        }

    }
```

Comment: where is equal sign in your query `List<Territory__c> terrList[select id from Territory__c where posatalcode__c: L.posatalcode];` this should be `List<Territory__c> terrList = [select id from Territory__c where posatalcode__c: L.posatalcode];`

Comment: You mean aside from the fact it's in a `for` loop?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this should get you on the right track..  I eyeballed this so some editing may be needed, but you really need to move that soql query out of the for loop

```
Map<String, Id> territories = new Map<String, Id>();
// Put postal codes into map
for(Lead record: Trigger.new) {
    territories.put(record.PostalCode, null);
}
// Ignore null postal code values
territories.remove(null);
// Populate map with ID values
for(Territory__c record:[SELECT PostalCode__c FROM Territory__c WHERE PostalCode__c IN :territories.keySet()]) {
    territories.put(record.PostalCode, record.id);
}
// Put new territory ID on lead: if no match, clears field.
for(Lead record: Trigger.new) {
    record.Territory__c = territories.get(record.PostalCode);
}
```

Comment: Your answer is essentially correct, but your code needs some work. Do you mind an edit?

Comment: Yup, go for it..

Answer (score 1):

You missed the "=" sign in your query.

```
List<Territory__c> terrList = [select id from Territory__c where postalcode__c = :L.postalcode];
```

It is best practice to avoid soql within for loops.